# How to override a custom taxonomy slug?

Tags: wordpress

How can I override the index/archive rewrite my taxonomy is trying to force? My taxonomy `gameboy` is forcing a normal page I have as `https://wwwmywebsite.com/games` to automatically redirect to `https://www.mywebsite.com/games/genre`. I think because the taxonomy includes the `gameboy` slug it is forcing an override.

I just want my normal page to stay /games/. Any help would be great. Below is some of my functions.php file.

```
// Register Custom Post Type
function fc_games() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => _x( 'Games', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'singular_name'         => _x( 'Game', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
        'menu_name'             => __( 'Games', 'text_domain' ),
        'name_admin_bar'        => __( 'Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'archives'              => __( 'Game Archives', 'text_domain' ),
        'attributes'            => __( 'Game Attributes', 'text_domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'     => __( 'Parent Game:', 'text_domain' ),
        'all_items'             => __( 'All Games', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'add_new'               => __( 'Add New Game Type', 'text_domain' ),
        'new_item'              => __( 'New Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'update_item'           => __( 'Update Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_item'             => __( 'View Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'view_items'            => __( 'View Games', 'text_domain' ),
        'search_items'          => __( 'Search Games', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found'             => __( 'Item Not found', 'text_domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'Item Not found in Trash', 'text_domain' ),
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Featured Image', 'text_domain' ),
        'set_featured_image'    => __( 'Set featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'remove_featured_image' => __( 'Remove featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'use_featured_image'    => __( 'Use as featured image', 'text_domain' ),
        'insert_into_item'      => __( 'Insert into item', 'text_domain' ),
        'uploaded_to_this_item' => __( 'Uploaded to this item', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list'            => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
        'items_list_navigation' => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
        'filter_items_list'     => __( 'Filter items list', 'text_domain' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'                 => __( 'Game', 'text_domain' ),
        'description'           => __( 'Games', 'text_domain' ),
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'supports'              => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies'            => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'genre_type' ),
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'public'                => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'menu_position'         => 20,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'show_in_admin_bar'     => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
        'can_export'            => true,
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'exclude_from_search'   => false,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'capability_type'       => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'games', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'fc_games', 0 );


function genre_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => _x( 'Taxonomy', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'snt' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'Genre', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'snt' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'Genres', 'snt' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'snt' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'snt' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'snt' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Item Name', 'snt' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Item', 'snt' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Item', 'snt' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'snt' ),
        'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'snt' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'snt' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove items', 'snt' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'snt' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'snt' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Items', 'snt' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'snt' ),
        'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'snt' ),
        'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'snt' ),
        'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'snt' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'hierarchical'               => false,
        'public'                     => true,
        'has_archive'                => false,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 
    'slug'          => 'games',
    'with_front'    => false 
),
        'with_front' => false,
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'genre_type', array( 'games' ), $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'genre_type', 0 );



function resources_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();
    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'genre_type',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ) );

    $post_type = 'games';
    foreach ($terms as $term) {    

        $rules['games/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)$'] = 'index.php?post_type=' . $post_type. '&resources_post_type=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';

    }
    // merge with global rules
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'resources_cpt_generating_rule');


function change_link( $permalink, $post ) {

    if( $post->post_type == 'games' ) {
        $resource_terms = get_the_terms( $post, 'genre_type' );
        $term_slug = '';
        if( ! empty( $resource_terms ) ) {
            foreach ( $resource_terms as $term ) {
                // The featured resource will have another category which is the main one
                if( $term->slug == 'featured' ) {
                    continue;
                }
                $term_slug = $term->slug;
                $term_slug = "genre/";
                break;
            }
        }

if( $post->ID !== 42011 ) {

        $permalink = get_home_url() ."/games/" . $term_slug . '' . $post->post_name;

    }

    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link',"change_link",10,2);


add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', function( $args, $post_type )
{
   // Make sure we only target the games post type
   if ( 'games' !== $post_type )
       return $args;

   $args['has_archive'] = false;
   $args['rewrite']     = false;
   $args[ 'rewrite' ][ 'with_front' ] = false;

   return $args;
}, PHP_INT_MAX, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The u in *slug* stands for unique. I know this is not a satisfying answer, but you just should not register the same slug for a taxonomy and for a page. Why don't you register the taxonomy with the slug "genre" or "games_genre" of whatever in the first place?

Comment: The slug for the taxonomy is *genre* under the custom post type *games*. It just so happens that a normal page like mywebsite.com/games/ is forcing a redirect to mywebsite.com/games/genre. Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: One of the issues is mywebsite.com/games has like all the categories of my genres so that's why I don't want it redirecting to just a single genre.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you want to override a taxonomy's slug, you can do this with ease, by adding this function into the functions.php of your child theme

```
function yourprefix_update_taxonomy_slug() {
    // get the arguments of the already-registered taxonomy
    $args = get_taxonomy( 'genre_type' ); // returns an object
    // make changes to the args
    // in this example there are three changes
    // again, note that it's an object
    $args->show_admin_column = true;
    $args->rewrite['slug'] = 'games';  /* HERE WE ADDED THE NEW SLUG */
    $args->rewrite['with_front'] = false;
    // re-register the taxonomy
    register_taxonomy( 'genre_type', 'games', (array) $args );
}
// hook it up to 11 so that it overrides the original register_taxonomy function
add_action( 'init', 'yourprefix_update_taxonomy_slug', 11 );
```

Note: After adding this function you need to reset your permalinks (Otherwise you will get 404 error when accessing the new links).